# Reading a file with hexadecimal data and store in to a list in python

Tags: python, hex

I have a file named `k_hex` which contains the below data. I read the data from file by using below command, and I want to save the data into a list.

```
hex_data = open('k_hex','r').read()
print hex_data
@0
45
4C
4C
41
00
07
00
00
10
```

I want my data in below format. How can I get it, I'm new to Python.

```
hex_data = [0x@0, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x4C, 0X41, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10]
```

Can you anyone please do let me know how to achieve the 2nd part?

Thanks.

Comment: If you read the file line at at time, you will make your life easier. As for the 2nd part, a whole number is going to display as an integer, unless you convert it to a hex string, so you'll get a list like ... '0x10']. Is that ok? (If not, why do you want a "format" in hex?)

Comment: @doctorlove i want something like this [0x11, 0x22, 0x33] , i dont want those quotes. Any way please . I need it in hex format because i need to write data into my vip memory in bytes .

Comment: You probably want them as bytes in that case. Not "numbers".

Comment: @doctorlove can you let me know for bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hex_data = ["0x" + hh for hh in hex_data.split()]
```

`hex_data.split()` splits your file into the list of pairs of hexadecimal symbols, and `"0x" + hh` will give the `Ox` characters in front of them.

Comment: is it possible to remove those single quotes ......
['0x@0', '0x45', '0x4C', '0x4C', '0x41', '0x00', '0x07', '0x00', '0x00', '0x10', '0x06', '0x6E', '0x00', '0x01', '0x00', '0xE4', '0x05']

Comment: Those single quotes are only Python syntax for strings - they are neither part of the string itself (e.g. in the memory or on the disk file), nor of the output of the `print()` function. You may convert them to integers with the `int()` function with the second parameter `16`, e. g. `int('0x6E', 16)` will give you the number `110`.